# Can I track goals on Bing ads when the destination URL is a virtual page view?

Tags: bing, goal-tracking

Can I use the universal event tracking (UET) to track conversions on the Bing ad platform when the destination URL is a virtual page view?

Comment: For reference here is the link to universal event tracking in Bing ads: https://advertise.bingads.microsoft.com/en-us/solutions/features/universal-event-tracking